# How to open a specific screen when local notification is shown in Flutter? app is closed

Tags: flutter, flutter-local-notification

I scheduled notification locally,I close the app(completely) and when the notification appears. I click on it and my app opens normally on "homepage"(same as clicking app icon to open it). I want to open a specific page ,lets say "page2()"
*** using the package : flutter_local_notifications: ^13.0.0

Answer (score 0):

use `FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage()` to handle message in background

Example:

```
void handleMessageOnBackground() {
    FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage().then(
      (remoteMessage) {
        if (remoteMessage != null) {
          String payload = json.encode(remoteMessage.data);
          //navigator two orther screen
        }
      },
    );
  }
```

And init `handleMessageOnBackground()` in `home_screen.dart` , not `main.dart`

`main.dart` > `splash_screen` > `home_screen`

**home_screen.dart**

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    handleMessageOnBackground();
  }
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you but it is a local notification! like a reminder !